# OS X: cycle between windows in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying desperately to figure out how to cycle through windows in Visual studio code. In Finder, there is a menu item `Cycle Through Windows` which I use frequently. However, this seems to be a Finder option. So I looked through the global shortcuts (since the requirement is probably the same for many applications) and assigned the `Move focus to next window` to shift-cmd-F1. This works in Finder and Text Editor, but not in Visual Studio Code. I checked if the key binding is overridden in VSC but I don't think so.

Has anyone got this figured out and can help me?

**edit**: just found that this is a global shortcut under System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Move focus to the next window. Unfortunately, Visual Code doesn't use it.

Comment: key bindings also vary depending extensions and configuration : i.e. the Vim extension

Answer (score 102):

I added the following shortcut to `keybindings.json`

```
{
    "key": "alt+tab",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickSwitchWindow"
}
```

`workbench.action.quickSwitchWindow` does exactly what I want and it has no default shortcut enabled (on a spanish keyboard at least).

Comment: Awesome, exactly what is needed and no weird 3 key shortcuts, which don't work on German keyboards, for example

Comment: If you have conflict between your MacOS and Windows shortcut, you can add "when": "isMacNative" in the shortcut description

Comment: If you like this, there is an even better version below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71830048/833960

Answer (score 79):

command ⌘ + ` is working nicely for me on macbook Pro.

Comment: Awesome. this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you !! Works perfectly on OS X 11.2.3 with Vscode 1.59.1

Comment: It doesn't work for maximized windows in a Space, unfortunately :( But there's an app called Witch that I use that lets you do that - https://manytricks.com/witch/

Comment: This works on Spanish keyboard or where ~ is not available but ` is

Comment: Doesn't work fine if your cursor is focused in the code area (or any text area). It just types the backquote where the cursor is.

Comment: CMD+`, does work if the 2 code windows are NOT full screen. CMD+`, does work NOT work  if the 2 code windows are  full screen. FYI.

Comment: This should be mark as answer

Answer (score 72):

So, finally found the solution: Though for some reason the system-wide shortcut for Move focus to next window does not work, there is another shortcut which does: `shift+cmd+~` :)

Found it here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Comment: ughhhh!
using a non-apple keyboard (Keychron K6) translate to:
shift+cmd+fn2+esc
...but works btw

Comment: Though your shortcut does work, it is no longer listed on the referenced page. It's now listed as "Command–Grave accent (`)", which I guess is a super-set of the previous one? It is less of a Vulcan Death Grip, so I'll take it.

Answer (score 50):

You can use `Switch window`  from command palette (command: `workbench.action.switchWindow`). The default shortcut is  `Ctrl + w`.

It lists all the open windows for you to select and go.

It's improved [further](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_14#_switch-window-improvements).

Comment: it closed all my windows on Mac.

Comment: @Laurence it is `control + W` on Mac.

Comment: If this answer closed some of your windows, you can reopen them with ctrl+shift+t :)

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> works for me unless I am in full screen mode. Alternatively, you can use the following shortcuts in full screen:

<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> then type "Switch Window".

Comment: Do we open the computer beforehand? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46559839/685540

Answer (score 12):

The newest version of Visual Code (1.55.2) has window switching enabled by default.
The hot key is `Control+W (⌃+W)`, which will bring down a command window for you to select which window to jump to.

Answer (score 11):

There seem to be tons of ways to cycle windows. I finally found one that worked for me:

```
shift + cmd + "{" or "}"
```

If you go to "window" in the application you'll see menu items for "Next Document" and "Previous Document".

Comment: It switches tabs in the same window for me in MacBook Pro. ^w works for me

Comment: This is what I was looking for, tab switcher.

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I rather use `quickOpenRecent` instead of `quickSwitchWindow` because it allows me to quickly switch between the last used window and the current one (stacked cycling instead of sequential). I have the following mapped to `alt+tab`:

```js
{
  "key": "alt+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenRecent",
  "when": "!inRecentFilesPicker"
},
{
  "key": "alt+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInRecentFilesPicker",
  "when": "inQuickOpen && inRecentFilesPicker"
},
{
  "key": "shift+alt+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigatePreviousInRecentFilesPicker",
  "when": "inQuickOpen && inRecentFilesPicker"
}
```

Comment: This works nicely.

Comment: This is cool. Thank you!

Comment: Love this! Thank you so much

Answer (score 7):

Just FYI, the shortcut for Ubuntu(Gnome 3) is alt + ` for switch between visual studio code (or other applications) windows.

Comment: For some reason it wasn't the default for me, but worked after I assigned it to `workbench.action.quickSwitchWindow`

Answer (score 5):

To cycle through windows that are in the same desktop, I use :

```
shift + command + `
```

Mac OS 12.2. Azerty, and VS Code 1.64.2

Answer (score 4):

Set the `Quick Switch Window...` keyboard shortcut to `command+N`
is a better work around for me.

Go to the menu `Code/Preferences/Keybord Shortcuts` and search for `quickSwitchWindow`

Comment: Finally! The other commands required 1 more click to select the window. This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm running macOS Monterey, `control^ + w` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

None of `` cmd+` `` `cmd+shift+F1` or `shift+cmd+~` work for me but `ctrl+cmd+\` does.

I'm using a UK Windows keyboard layout - not sure if that affected it..

**Edit:** I originally found that `cmd+\` was working but having restarted VS Code that changed to `ctrl+cmd+\` - very odd

Comment: ctrl+cmd+\ works best on ventura 13

Answer (score 3):

if you know how to open keybodard shortcuts from vscode,
type "switch" in input box which has a placeholder "Type to search in Keybindings". you will see "switch window...".

i am using macbook and ^ + W is an default shortcut key for switching windows in between.

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl + w` (`[^ + w]`) is default keyboard shortcut in VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

I use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to quickly switch between open vs code windows. This is very easy.

```json
    {
        "key": "alt+`",
        "command": "workbench.action.quickSwitchWindow",
        "when": "!inQuickOpen"
    },
    {
        "key": "alt+`",
        "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectNext",
        "when": "inQuickOpen"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+alt+`",
        "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectPrevious",
        "when": "inQuickOpen"
    }
```

Comment: this works but I'm still wondering why we can't use cmd instead of alt here; and also why  doesn't vscode let the system switch windows with the standard cmd+` command.

Answer (score 1):

Although, it is not quick switch, you can use `control (^)` + `W` to open up the menu of all your open windows. Alternatively you can just search for Switch window after pressing `Command + Shift + P`

Answer (score 0):

in VsCode press **Ctrl+Shift+P** and search **Open next editor** and click on Setting button and change it to your shortcut keys!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to setting the keyboard shortcut in VSCode itself, for macOS, update or re-enable the missing shortcut:

[image]

For me, this turned out being a better alternative, since unfortunately the Cmd + ` shortcut cannot be registered in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple VSCode panels open, and coming from a danish keyboard on Mac, I went into system preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts... -> Keyboard -> Double clicked the 'Move focus to next window' to change the cmd+` to cmd+<.

Now I'm able to switch through e.g. VSCode if I have opened multiple instances.